# Update txt file with php

Tags: php, file, file-handling

I am trying to update content in the txt file such that everytime register is pressed +1 one gets added to that particular data. So far it displays data and register button but when I click it, it doesn't add one. How do I achieve that?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

  <?php
  $myfile = fopen("addcourse.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
  // Output one line until end-of-file
   while(!feof($myfile)) {

        echo fgets($myfile) . '<form id="h1" class="rounded" action="final.php" target="" method="post"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"  class="button" value="Register" /> </form>' "<br>";

       }
  fclose($myfile);
   ?>

</body>
</html>


 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$data = $_POST['field1'];
$ret = file_put_contents('/addcourse.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    echo "$ret bytes written to file";
}
}
 else {
  die('no post data to process');
  }
```

Comment: Any error you get?

Comment: None because this code is correct but I am trying to add 1 everytime submit is clicked. which it doesn't

Comment: please add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after `<?php` and check for possible errors

Comment: I turned on error_reporting but there aren't any errors, If I have to add "+1" string next to the data I am fetching how would you say that could be done?

Answer (score 0):

use php's `fwrite` instead of `file_put_content`.
See the PHP manual of `fwrite` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: maybe your www folder or www-data user got no R/W permission on the desired directory ... also, try debugging with `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.

Comment: I turned on error_reporting but there aren't any errors, If I have to add "+1" string next to the data I am fetching how would you say that could be done?

Comment: as far as i can see you are not posting any data for further processing. `$data = $_POST['field1'];` -> there is no such form field in your 1st part so it won't post any data.

Comment: if you're trying to post field1, you'd have to add a form field like `<input type="text" name="field1">`

Comment: I apologize that is actually submit instead of field1

Answer (score 0):

you can use fwrite method to write into file.

```
$file = fopen($filename,"a+");
fwrite($file,$yourText);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: I turned on error_reporting but there aren't any errors, If I have to add "+1" string next to the data I am fetching how would you say that could be done?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to update txt file

```
<?php
$fn = "file.txt";
$file = fopen($fn, "a+");
$size = filesize($fn);

if($_POST['addition']) fwrite($file, $_POST['addition']);

$text = fread($file, $size);
fclose($file);
?>
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="post">
<textarea><?=$text?></textarea><br/>
<input type="text" name="addition"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looping through all the lines in the file to display the form(s). How many lines are there? If it's more than one, you're going to have to jump through some hoops to update just one of them.

But assuming it's just one line, there's no need to pass that as a parameter when you can (and probably should) just get the value directly from the file:

```
$data = 1 + file_get_contents('/addcourse.txt');
$ret = file_put_contents('/addcourse.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Note that this will fail if two processes attempt to update the file at the same time, as the second process will simply duplicate the same value as the first process, and instead of adding 2 (one for each process) it will just add 1.